# vite proxy - forward `/admin` to other vue/vite app

Tags: vue.js, vite, http-proxy

I have two vue apps. One is the user app (http://127.0.0.1:3000), the other the admin app (http://127.0.0.1:3001).

In the user app exists a button/link that redirects the user to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin`, under which the admin app should be showed.

The problem is, nerveless of the configuration of the proxy, it always show the user app, instead of the admin app. Even when the html code idicates that the content of the admin app is returned.

Vite config:

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

const {
    BACKEND_PROTOCOL,
    BACKEND_HOST,
    BACKEND_PORT,
    ADMIN_PROTOCOL,
    ADMIN_HOST,
    ADMIN_PORT
} = process.env = Object.assign({
    BACKEND_PROTOCOL: "http",
    BACKEND_HOST: "127.0.0.1",
    BACKEND_PORT: "8080",
    ADMIN_PROTOCOL: "http",
    ADMIN_HOST: "127.0.0.1",
    ADMIN_PORT: "3001"
}, process.env);

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue()
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    server: {
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        proxy: {
            "/api": {
                target: `${BACKEND_PROTOCOL}://${BACKEND_HOST}:${BACKEND_PORT}`,
                ws: true,
                xfwd: true
            },
            "/auth": {
                target: `${BACKEND_PROTOCOL}://${BACKEND_HOST}:${BACKEND_PORT}`,
                xfwd: true
            },
            // does not work, loads every time the user ui, not admin ui
            "/admin": {
                target: `${ADMIN_PROTOCOL}://${ADMIN_HOST}:${ADMIN_PORT}`,
                xfwd: true,
                changeOrigin: true,
                configure: (proxy, _options) => {
                    proxy.on('error', (err, _req, _res) => {
                        console.log('proxy error', err);
                    });
                    proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req, _res) => {
                        console.log('Sending Request to the Target:', req.method, req.url);
                    });
                    proxy.on('proxyRes', (proxyRes, req, _res) => {
                        console.log('Received Response from the Target:', proxyRes.statusCode, req.url);
                    });
                },
                rewrite: (path) => {
                    console.log("/admin", path, "replacE:", path.replace(/^\/admin/, ''));
                    return path.replace(/^\/admin/, '')
                }
            }
        }
    },
    build: {
        outDir: "build",
        emptyOutDir: true
    },
    clearScreen: false
});
```

`curl -v http://127.0.0.1:3000` (user app)

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://127.0.0.1:3000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: text/html
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Etag: W/"411-DeqPWoDYIM10IgGd7GmzdbxCSNc"
< Date: Fri, 11 Aug 2023 15:30:35 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
< Content-Length: 1041
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>

  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
  <title>OpenHaus</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #app {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app" class="gardien-background"></div>
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
</body>

* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

[image]

`curl -v http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin` (admin app through user app proxy)

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /admin HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< content-type: text/html
< cache-control: no-cache
< etag: W/"467-ib/5PPaNHA99cEUmT0owWr6niTc"
< date: Fri, 11 Aug 2023 15:31:44 GMT
< connection: close
< content-length: 1127
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>

  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
  <title>OpenHaus</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
</body>

<style>
  :disabled {
    pointer-events: auto !important;
    cursor: not-allowed !important;
  }


  * {
    /*
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;    
    font-family: 'Roboto Thin', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto Light', sans-serif;
    */
    font-family: 'Roboto Medium', sans-serif;
    /*
     font-family: 'Roboto Black', sans-serif;
    */
  }
</style>

* Closing connection 0
```

[image]

`curl -v http://127.0.0.1:3001` (admin app, direct)

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://127.0.0.1:3001/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 3001 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:3001
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: text/html
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Etag: W/"467-ib/5PPaNHA99cEUmT0owWr6niTc"
< Date: Fri, 11 Aug 2023 15:32:28 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
< Content-Length: 1127
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>

  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
  <title>OpenHaus</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
</body>

<style>
  :disabled {
    pointer-events: auto !important;
    cursor: not-allowed !important;
  }


  * {
    /*
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;    
    font-family: 'Roboto Thin', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto Light', sans-serif;
    */
    font-family: 'Roboto Medium', sans-serif;
    /*
     font-family: 'Roboto Black', sans-serif;
    */
  }
</style>

* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

[image]

Can anyone point to me out, why through the user vite proxy, the admin app is not shown rendered even when the http response looks right?

My first thought was that the vite client for hot reloading does something nasty, but i cant point out why. Does it intercept and modify http requests?

Thanks for any hint.

EDIT: Dont know if this is needed to be known, but the routing mode in both apps is set to `createWebHashHistory()`.

Comment: How is curl response supposed to indicate that 127.0.0.1:3000/admin works wrong way? Fwiw, it's more straightforward to make admin app url configurable, so you could use different domains in dev env. Unless you rely on same origin cookies, this shouldn't be a problem. You probably have problems with a proxy at least because hot reload uses web sockets

Comment: `How is curl response supposed to indicate that 127.0.0.1:3000/admin works wrong way?` Thats the point, its not. Looks right to me. The only explanation i have is, that in the html code the vite client is loaded from the "base" url (`/@vite/client`). Which is in both cases (thorugh the user ui app) `127.0.0.1:3000`. So for user and admin app the user vite client is loaded. Dunno, if this has any effect on my problem.

Comment: Would make sense to make them unique, just to figure out what's going on, and check what happens in network tab. I didn't examine thoroughly how Vite dev server works, but it can have something to do with that absolute paths are used for resources, `/src/main.js`, etc, no base url. Any way, I'd advise to go with the approach suggested above, it's workable regardless of build tool and doesn't require to dig deep into its internals